# How to Avoid loop persist in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, fetch

I have 2 entities

Article

```
Long id;
String pealkiri;
List<Authors> authors;
```

Author

```
Long id;
String name;
List<Article> articles;
```

When I used `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` it was enought to WEB. Because when I asked `List` it returned `Articles` without `Autors`. When I asked some `Article` it returned `Article` with `Authors` list.

Now I need add REST functionality with JSON reterned.

I need some query like

```
getAricles;

getAuthors;
```

Both of them have to return

getAricles;

```
[
{"id":367, 
    "pealkiri":"pealkiri1", 
    "autorid":
    [
        {"id":24, 
        "name":"Author24"},
        {"id":25, 
        "name":"Author25"}
    ]
},
{"id":368, 
    "pealkiri":"pealkiri2", 
    "autorid":
    [
        {"id":26, 
        "name":"Author26"},
        {"id":27, 
        "name":"Author27"}
    ]
}
]
```

getAuthors:

```
[
    {
        "id":24, 
        "name":"Author24",
        "articles":
        [
            {"id":367, 
            "pealkiri":"pealkiri1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id":25, 
        "name":"Author25",
        "articles":
        [
            {"id":367, 
            "pealkiri":"pealkiri1"}
        ]
    }
]
```

To avoid lazy exception I tried to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` on Article's author fild and on Author's Article filed, but comes chain:

Article has Author -> Author has Article -> Article has Author - Author has Article and so on.

Now Hibernate generates 100-s of queries for 1 Article.

Comment: Can you use [named queries](http://www.javajee.com/named-queries-in-hql-with-hibernate-43)?

Comment: "When I used fetch = FetchType.LAZY it was enought to WEB" - not true.

Comment: to:user3707125 -> Tried: removed @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN), fetch = FetchType.LAZY is back. With named queries using joins it doesn't return subitems(authors in article)-> Lazy exception. Without FetchType.LAZY is the same.

Comment: To Roman C: I mean it was enought for my task.